# Select count(*) from people where id =?;

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

Using MacOS - Java - MySql 8.0 - jdbc 8.0 - Intellij.

When I run the this (`Select count(*) from people where id =?;`) replacing the ? With the number 1 it works fine. But when I do this:

```
for (Person person: people) {
            int id = person.getId();

checkStmt.setInt(1, id);
            
ResultSet checkResult = checkStmt.executeQuery(checkSql);
```

I get this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Running the debugger the value of id returned from the array is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already called `setInt`, you then throw it away by using a different query. Change

```
checkStmt.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet checkResult = checkStmt.executeQuery(checkSql);
```

to

```
checkStmt.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet checkResult = checkStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I had a brain fart but just couldn't remove the fog.